# Retrofit and usage of absolute URLs

Tags: retrofit

How can you handle in Retrofit absolute URLs for some calls?

I am using a combination of dagger, retrofit and OKHttp. I provide a @Singleton RestAdapter with the selected endpoint (Production, Staging, etc) which it is formed from the BASE URL.

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    RestAdapter providesRestAdapter(Endpoint endpoint,
                                    ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper,
                                    Client client,
                                    ApiRequestInterceptor headers) {

        return new RestAdapter.Builder() //
                .setClient(client) //
                .setEndpoint(endpoint) //
                .setConverter(new JacksonConverter(jacksonObjectMapper))
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setRequestInterceptor(headers) //
                .build();
    }
```

The problem is that the REST service, for some cases, returns the URL for the content to be loaded in ABSOLUTE format meaning something like http://someurl.com/resource?sort=ascendent and not the preferable /resouce?sort=ascendent (without the BASE_URL)

Now the question is how I can create the interface of the service to deal with such scenario?

I was thinking something like:

```
public interface PlaceholdersService {

    @GET("{placeholderHref}")
    public void getPlaceholder(@EncodedPath("placeholderHref") String placeholderHref);

}
```

The problem is that I am not sure if the BASE URL set in the Endpoint previously when creating the RestAdapter will be added (can't test it at the moment).

Another though was to create a new RestAdapter specially for this case with an Endpoint set to a null or empty string fixed point like Endpoints.newFixedEndpoint(null) or Endpoints.newFixedEndpoint("").

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using absolute URLs with Retrofit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116395/using-absolute-urls-with-retrofit)

Answer (score 0):

Digging a little bit I just realised there is an open issue for this manner in Github https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/333

It has been moved the discussion to the V2 of the library to discuss if will be supported or not in that version.

This means that if supported, won't do it for a while. Is there any suggestion or workaround you can suggest to surpass this issue for the moment?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by creating new adapter with specified URL and use an empty path in my interface. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116395/using-dynamic-url-with-retrofit/28121534#28121534) is my question and my own answer.

Hope it helps.