# Using absolute URLs with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have a [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) API that I'm working with and in many cases I need to send request (with different methods) to a URL that I get back from API. Meaning I don't want to hardcode the path of URL in my retrofit api interface but what I want is just sending a simple request using retrofit to that URL.
I'm using Volley now and I know that I can use OkHttp for this purpose but I was wondering if there is a nice way of doing such thing in Retrofit?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Recently Square has released the [Retrofit v2.0.0 BETA](http://square.github.io/retrofit/#download) and it has a built-in support for dynamic URLs. Even though the Library is in Beta, based on what [Jake Wharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton) told us in DroidCon NYC 2015, all the apis are stable and will not change. I'm personally adding it to my production so its up to you.

You will find the following links useful if you decide to do the upgrade:
[Jake Wharton presentation @ DroidCon NYC 2015](https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/simple-http-with-retrofit-2-droidcon-nyc-2015)
[A very good guide on the changes](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en)

In simple word, you can now use the api annotations (like @GET or @POST and others) without any path and then you pass in a @URL to your api method that the method will use to call.

----------------Retrofit 1.x

I figured out a nice way for doing this and would like to share it.

The trick is to use the dynamic URL as your End Point in the creation of RestAdapter and then have a empty path on your API interface.

Here is how I did it:

```
public RestAdapter getHostAdapter(String baseHost){
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(baseHost)
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .build();

    return restAdapter;
}
```

I build my restAdapter using this method and then I have this in my interface: 
**(this will not work if your URL has query parameters added to it. See next answer for solution to that case)**

```
public interface General {
    @GET("/")
    void getSomething(Callback<SomeObject> callback);
}
```

and finally using them like this:

```
getHostAdapter("YOUR_DYNAMIC_URL").create(General.class)
    .getSomething(new Callback<SomeObject>(){
        ...
    })
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please explain?
Is it something similar to @ GET ("http://...") - absolute URL

Comment: Sure, no, you can not do @ GET ("http://...") because anything you put in as parameter for GET (or any other retrofit method in API Interface) will be used as the relative path to your base URL (which you should provide when creating the RestAdapter) that means if you use what you just mentioned the request will go to something like http://your.base.url/http://... which is not what you want. instead my trick is to have an empty path (meaning just a forward slash "/") and provide the full URL of the destination as your base URL and create a new RestAdapter for each request.

Answer (score 3):

In case that your URL has query parameters on it, the above solution will not work since it will add the '/' at the end of your base URL. for example if your URL is

```
https://www.google.com/?q=test
```

then the above solution will try to send the request to

```
https://www.google.com/?q=test/
```

which will fail because of mall format.

What we can do is one extra step and parsing the url. By parsing I mean just taking out all URL parameters and sending them in a `QueryMap`.

#### Here is how:

We should have the same structure describe above with a little change to our interface

```
public interface General {
    @GET("/")
    void getSomething(@QueryMap Map<String,String> queryMap, Callback<SomeObject> callback);
}
```

I just added a `QueryMap` to the above interface and now we can use this parser method:

```
public static void getSomething(@NonNull String urlString, @NonNull Callback<SomeObject> callback){
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlString);
    Set<String> queryParameterNames = uri.getQueryParameterNames();
    String host = uri.getHost();
    HashMap<String,String> queryMap = new HashMap<>();
    Iterator<String> iterator = queryParameterNames.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String queryName = iterator.next();
        String queryParameter = uri.getQueryParameter(queryName);
        queryMap.put(queryName, queryParameter);
    }

    getHostAdapter(host)
        .create(General.class)
        .getSomething(queryMap, callback);
}
```

now you can call this method like this:

```
getSomething("https://www.google.com/?q=test");
```

Enjoy coding.

Note: `QueryMap` was added on [Retrofit v1.4.0](https://github.com/square/retrofit/releases/tag/parent-1.4.0)

Answer (score 3):

I also need a path on my URL, so I did this:

```
    @GET("/{path}")
void getMatcherUrl(@Path(value = "path", encode = false) String path, @QueryMap Map<String, String> queryMap, RestCallback<MatcherResponse> matcherResponse);

/**
     * Need to create a custom method because i need to pass a absolute url to the retrofit client
     *
     * @param urlString
     * @param matcherResponse
     */
    public void getMatcherUrl(@NonNull String urlString, @NonNull RestCallback<MatcherResponse> matcherResponse) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlString);
        Set<String> queryParameterNames = uri.getQueryParameterNames();
        String host = uri.getHost();
        String path = (uri.getPath().startsWith("/")) ? uri.getPath().substring(1) : uri.getPath();
        HashMap<String, String> queryMap = new HashMap<>();
        Iterator<String> iterator = queryParameterNames.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String queryName = iterator.next();
            String queryParameter = uri.getQueryParameter(queryName);
            queryMap.put(queryName, queryParameter);
        }

        getApiCoreService(host)
                .getMatcherUrl(path, queryMap, matcherResponse);
    }

    public ApiCoreService getApiCoreService(String host) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(host))
            this.endpoint = new RestEndpoint(RemoteConfigurationManager.getInstance().getApiCore(), "ApiCore");
        else
            this.endpoint = new RestEndpoint(host, "ApiCore");
        return apiCoreService;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to above two answers, Here is a working class that makes use of Queryparam and fires the absolute URL

```
public class VideoClient {

private static final String TAG = "VideoCLient";
private final RestAdapter restAdapter;
private General apiService;
private String hostName;
private LinkedHashMap<String, String> queryMap;
private String Url_Path;

public VideoClient(String BASE_URL) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Base url is "+BASE_URL);
    hostName =getHostNameAndGenerateQueryMap(BASE_URL);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .create();
    RequestInterceptor interceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {}
    };

    restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint("http://"+hostName)
            .setClient(new OkClient())
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setRequestInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();
private String getHostNameAndGenerateQueryMap(String urlString) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlString);
    Url_Path = (uri.getPath().startsWith("/")) ? uri.getPath().substring(1) : uri.getPath();
    Set<String> queryParameterNames = uri.getQueryParameterNames();
    String host = uri.getHost();
    queryMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    Iterator<String> iterator = queryParameterNames.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String queryName = iterator.next();
        String queryParameter = uri.getQueryParameter(queryName);
        Log.d(TAG,"query name "+queryName +" query param "+queryParameter);

        queryMap.put(queryName, queryParameter);
    }
    return host;
}

public interface General {

    /*void getVideo(@Path("auth_token") String authId,
                  @Query("et") String systemTime,@Query("service_id") String serviceID,
                  @Query("protocol") String scheme,@Query("play_url") String url,
                  @Query("us") String us,Callback<String> callback);
    */
    @GET("/{path}")
     getVideo(@Path(value="path", encode=false)String path,@QueryMap LinkedHashMap<String, String> queryMap);
}

public void getVideoDetails() {
    Log.i("firing", "getVideoApi");

    Log.d(TAG, "firing " + Url_Path + " function");
    restAdapter.create(General.class).getVideo(Url_Path,queryMap, new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void success( Object o, Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG," Success Response is "+response );
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failure " + "Internal Error" + error);
        }
    });
}
```