# How to setup Retrofit with no baseUrl

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

My apiPath is fully dynamic. I am having items containing fields such us "ipAddress" and "SSLprotocol". Based on them I can build my url:

```
private String urlBuilder(Server server) {
    String protocol;
    String address = "";

    if (AppTools.isDeviceOnWifi(activity)) {
        address = serverToConnect.getExternalIp();
    } else if (AppTools.isDeviceOnGSM(activity)) {
        address = serverToConnect.getInternalIp();
    }

    if (server.isShouldUseSSL()) {
        protocol = "https://";
    } else {
        protocol = "http://";
    }
    return protocol + address;
}
```

So my protocol + address can be: http:// + 192.168.0.01:8010 = http://192.168.0.01:8010

And I would like to use it like that:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("{fullyGeneratedPath}/json/token.php")
Observable<AuthenticationResponse> authenticateUser(
            @Path("fullyGeneratedPath") String fullyGeneratedPath,
            @Field("login") String login,
            @Field("psw") String password,
            @Field("mobile") String mobile);
```

So full path for authenticateUser would be http://192.168.0.01:8010/json/token.php - for example.

That means I don't need any basePath because I create whole basePath myself depending on server I want to connect to.

My retrofit setup is:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient,
            Converter.Factory converterFactory,
            AppConfig appConfig) {
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder();
    builder.client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl(appConfig.getApiBasePath())
            .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create());

    return builder.build();
}
```

If I remove baseUrl then I get error that this parameter is required. So I set my apiBasePath to:

```
public String getApiBasePath() {
    return "";
}
```

And then I get error instantly after I create retrofit instance:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL:
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Does it let you use "http://" as the base url?

Comment: Hmm no, I get: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL: http://

Comment: you could use the @Url annotation. But you will have to build every url completely

Comment: If I used @Url then what should be set to my retrofit baseUrl if it cannot be "".

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From [source](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en) (*New URL resolving concept*) you can simply specify whole path in post request.

> Moreover we also can declare a full URL in @Post in Retrofit 2.0:
>
> ```
> public interface APIService {
>
>     @POST("http://api.nuuneoi.com/special/user/list")
>     Call<Users> loadSpecialUsers();
>
> }
> ```
>
> Base URL will be ignored for this case.

Comment: You can use this trick with every method out there (e.g. `@GET`)

Comment: Thanks. I used this solution before, but couldn't understand, why Retrofit didn't return a response. Then I realised that it returned an exception "retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 403" in try-catch.

Comment: This is the way to create a call with no base url, but the question was "How set Retrofit up with no base url ?". Isn't it different?

Comment: agree with @NayMak

Answer (score 11):

just use like this

```
public interface UserService {  
    @GET
    public Call<ResponseBody> profilePicture(@Url String url);
}
```

[source](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-use-dynamic-urls-for-requests)

Comment: Doesn't this still require you to setup RetroFit with a Base URL (that gets ignored on this particular call)? When I forced all my calls to have URLs as parameters and remove the Base URL, it still threw an Exception complaining  :/

Answer (score 9):

With Retrofit 2 you have to put base url anyway. If it is not known then you just can put any url, usually, it is good to use `http://localhost/`.

Answer (score 0):

`retrofit version :2.9.0 | gson version / okhttp : auto-set by retrofit`

The original solution did not worked for me, as my query was using `GET` . But here's something that might work for you :

```kotlin
interface DownloaderApi {
    @GET(".")
    fun getData(): Call<List<TeacherDto>>

}
```

and

```kotlin
class TeacherDataDownloader {
    private val downloaderApi: DownloaderApi

    init {
        val convertor = Gson()
        val convertorFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(convertor)
        val retrofit =
            Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(FULL_URL).addConverterFactory(convertorFactory).build()

        downloaderApi = retrofit.create(DownloaderApi::class.java)
    }

    fun getListOfTeachersSync(): List<TeacherDto>? = downloaderApi.getData().execute().body()

}
```

This solution works for me partially , because some of the links that I use ends with `/` (eg: `const val FULL_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"` ). **However this solution only works for APIs ending with  a `/`**

For URLS not ending with a `/` (eg : github gists) , you have to use the default methods and pass the end-path as parameter.

Answer (score -1):

If you're okay with creating a new `RestAdapter` instance each time you want to make an api call, you could create a new adapter with the base url as a paramter.

[Using absolute URLs with Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116395/using-absolute-urls-with-retrofit)

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can do. I have done like this:

```
public APIHelper(BaseActivity activity) {

    String url = Common.getAPIUrl();

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint(url)
            .build();

    methods = restAdapter.create(IAppService.class);
}
```

Basically you need to create object of retrofit once you have known the endpoint url. I guess no more explanation is needed as code is self explanatory.

Assuming that only base url is getting changed.

Answer (score -2):

My way to use retrofit

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.8'
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
```

And here i have a generic class and inside i have my method

```
public static AppServiceApi setMyRetrofit(){
    Retrofit retrofit = null;
    AppServiceApi appServices = null;
    if (retrofit == null){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();                                                                                  //
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).client(getClient())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
        appServices = retrofit.create(AppServiceApi.class);
    }
    return appServices;
}

public static OkHttpClient getClient(){
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor=new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            /*.connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)*/.build();
    return client;
}
```

where AppServiceApi interface have all my end urls and method type

Comment: This still sets up RetroFit with a Base URL. The best way to get around this is to simply provide the URL in a parameter with the annotation of the call like @Inverce did in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844301/2128921)