# Download Authorised images link using Retrofit2 in android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I saw similar questions in StackOverflow **but this is a little different**. I want to download the Authorised image from the server, to download the image I want to use the Authorized token.

> Retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://example.com/api/") 
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

> IService

```
@GET
Call<ResponseBody> getImage(@Url String url, @Header("Authorization") String token);
```

> Calling place

IService service= retrofit.create(IService.class);

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.getImage(url, "Bearer " + token);

call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ");
    }
});
```

you can see the above code, How my usecase is different from other cases is, in the retrofit instance class, I provided the Baseurl, but in my case, there is no base URL only an image link is available

I used postman to send the request with the authorized token, and successfully downloaded the image, but here, there is no need for a base URL, if I keep the baseurl as empty, I'm getting an exception.

How to solve this issue, Thank you

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676372/6819340?

Comment: first thank for your response, i have tried that one as well, I'm getting 404 error code for that